# Neo4j - pagination from Ruby on Rails

Tags: neo4j, neo4j.rb

What is the best pagination option from Ruby on Rails when using Neo4j?
I am looking to paginate with Kaminari, will_paginate gem or even Bootstrap.
Any recommendation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-will_paginate_redux, I find it works well. Neo4j.rb has a [basic pagination class](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/blob/master/lib/neo4j/paginated.rb) built in, too, so it might be enough to use that if you need something simple without the view helpers. If you want Kaminari, there's https://github.com/megorei/kaminari-neo4j, built by a frequent contributor to Neo4j.rb. I haven't used it but his work is always very good.

Answer (score 5):

I've used kaminari with the `kaminari-neo4j` gem and had luck with it.

Chris added support for will_paginate a while ago, but I'm not sure if it still works:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-will_paginate_redux

I'll send him a link to this question and see if he has a suggestion

Comment: Many thanks for the hints. I will start with kaminari since our apps already use this. If this is not going to work properly I will switch to will_paginate.